# codeigniter pagination - how to keep on same page after deleting row

Tags: codeigniter

I am using codeigniter pagination library and doing update and delete through form. The problem is when I delete or update any record after delete or update I redirected back to 1st page even if I am at 4th page. How I can  redirected to the same page at which I have done update or delete.
Here is my controller code for update and delete functions:

```
  public function update_att(){

      if(isset($_POST['update'])){
        $u_id = $_POST['at_id'];

        if($_POST['status']=="Present"){

            $data = array(
                  'status'=>"Absent"
            );
            $this->db->where('at_id', $u_id);
            $this->db->update('attendence', $data);
        }elseif ($_POST['status']=="Absent") {
            $data = array(
                  'status'=>"Present"
            );
            $this->db->where('at_id', $u_id);
            $this->db->update('attendence', $data);
        }

    redirect("usr/att_list", "refresh");
   }
}

 public function delete_att(){

     if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
        $at_id = $_POST['at_id'];
        $this->db->where('at_id', $at_id);
        $this->db->delete('attendence');
      }
      redirect("usr/att_list" );
 }
```

Currently I am redirecting to the first page , any suggestion how I redirect to that page where I have done delete or update.

Comment: Save what page (or offset) you're on in a session variable or a url query string `?offset=123` and read it back after the redirect.

Comment: can you please write the code i'll be very thankful to you, i read about this solution before but don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<input type='hidden' name='current_page' value='<?php echo $current_page?>' />` to your form.

Keep in mind you need to populate `$current_page` with something like

```
    $current_page = ''; // empty means first page
    if( isset($_REQUEST['current_page'] ){
       $current_page = $_REQUEST['current_page'];
    }
```

Then based on your sample you just modifiy the `redirect` path as follows (for both your functions):

```
public function delete_att(){

     if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
        $at_id = $_POST['at_id'];
        $this->db->where('at_id', $at_id);
        $this->db->delete('attendence');
      }
      redirect("usr/att_list".(strlen($current) ? "?".$current : "" );
 }
```

#### Note:

Your path to your page should look something like this `domain.com/controller/your_page_with_pagination/?current_page=A_NUMBER` then in your `controller/your_page_with_pagination` you adjust the  data you wish to output based on `$_GET['current_page']`

**Edit based on your link:**

```
    public function att_list($id = ""){
         /**
          * Keep your data in array
          */
         $this->data = array();

         /**
          * Add the page number ($id) to the array 
          * Check for url /:id first , or else check for a $_GET/$_POST current_page (this will be triggered when you submit your form)
          */
         $this->data['current_page'] = is_numeric($id) ? $id : (isset($_REQUEST['current_page'] ? $_REQUEST['current_page']: 0);

         /**
          * This is your 'keep on the same page' line
          * $this->data['current_page'] will act as an offset in your query
          * You can read about 'offset' here https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp
          * $this->data['my_desired_records'] must be generated into your <form> ... </form> , and the same form must contain the input with name='current_page'
          */
         $this->data['my_desired_records'] = $this->your_model->get_data($this->data['current_page']);

         /**
          * Pass the whole array into your view
          */
         $this->load->view('path/to/view', $this->data);

      }
```

Then in your view add in your form `<input type='hidden' name='current_page' value='<?php echo $this->data['current_page']?>' />`

Comment: @sameedulhassan i have edited my answer with the minimal logic for your method, and added some explanation, i hope it is clear.